A SAT question about SAT property
Two space aliens walk into your home, both claiming to be oracles for the Boolean Satisfiability (SAT)
decision problem. They both always give a yes/no answer in constant time for any SAT instance, and
are each self-consistent (i.e. each always gives the same answer for the same instance). However, one
is a true oracle and the other is a shameless impostor, and you have a large SAT instance F upon which
they disagree (i.e. one claims that this SAT instance F satisfiable and the other one claims that F is not
satisfiable). Show that it is possible to expose the impostor within time polynomial in the size of that SAT
instance F.

Suppose $F$ is a formula with variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and Alien $1$ was the one that said that $F$ is satisfiable.
Then iteratively do the following for all $i = 1, \ldots, n$:

Set $F_1 \gets F \land x_i$ and $F_2 \gets F \land \neg x_i$ ask Alien $1$ whether it is saisfiable or not.
If Alien $1$ says that both $F_1$ and $F_2$ are unsatisfiable, then Alien $1$ is the imposter, otherwise set $F \gets F_k$, where $F_k$ is a formula out of $\{F_1, F_2\}$ that Alien $1$ claimed to be satisfiable.
If Alien $2$ at some point claims that $F$ became satisfiable, then Alien $2$ is the imposter as $F$ cannot go from unsatifiable to satisfiable by adding more clauses.

After all variables are handled (if no alien has lost by now), check whether the resulting assignment that Alien $1$ implicitly gave by claiming $F_1$ or $F_2$ is correct in each iteration is indeed satisfying for the original $F$, which determines whether Alien $1$ or $2$ is the imposter.

There are two cases, either $F$ is satisfiable, or it is not.

If the formula is satisfiable, you can use the oracle to determine a satisfying assignment, by simply extending the formula to $F \cap (x_1)$.  If this is satisfiable, you continue to $x_2$, otherwise you extend $F$ to $F \cap (\neg x_1)$, and so on.  One of the oracles will give you a satisfying assignment, and this is the true oracle.
If the formula is not satisfiable, you use the same trick, but now the "oracle" that claimed that $F$ is satisfiable will necessarily end up in a contradiction.

In any case, you need at most $2n$ many calls to each oracle.

A SAT/UNSAT claim needs to come with a proof.
A SAT proof is easy, it is simply the satisfying assignment.
This can be checked in O(n) time by verifying that A: this assignment indeed satisfies every clause it touches and B: that the assignment touches all literals in every clause.
An UNSAT proof is basically a trace of the SAT solver.
These traces are checked using a theorem prover and proofs of (mathematical) correctness of these provers are required for it to be considered a prover.
The prover runs in polynomial time O(x), where x is the size of the proof, but unfortunatly, the size of proof scales exponentially in the worst case, so time O(2^n) and space O(2^n).
Obviously your space aliens need to produce the UNSAT proof in a format that YOUR prover can process, because you cannot trust the alien prover.
If you have proofs, AND you know that the assertion that one oracle always lies and another always tells the truth is, in fact, true. Than you can point out the TRUE oracle simply be checking the SAT certificate in O(n) time.
If you don't know this, it is still possible for the assignment to be SAT, even through the given SAT assignment is incorrect (there may exist some other, unknown SAT assignment).
You then have to check the UNSAT proof.
Note that as far as I know there are no SAT solvers with formal proofs of correctness, so currently, you cannot trust an actual oracle without a proof.

The question clearly asks for the case where there is no proof, just an assertion. (And delivering a proof in constant time might also be difficult.)
